# I have a specific programing task

Tags: python, list, sum

Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range 13..19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens. Write a separate helper "def fix_teen(n):"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen rule. In this way, you avoid repeating the teen code 3 times (i.e. "decomposition"). Define the helper below and at the same indent level as the main no_teen_sum().

My solution:-

```
def no_teen_sum(a,b,c):
    sum=0
    lst=[13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
    def fix_teen(n):
      s=0
      if n >=13 and n<= 19:
        if n==15:
          s=15
        elif n==16:
          s=16
        else:
          s=0
      return s
    if (a not in lst) and (b not in lst) and (c not in lst):
        sum=a+b+c
    elif  a in lst :
        sum=fix_teen(a)+b+c
        if b in lst:
            sum=fix_teen(a)+fix_teen(b)+c
    elif b in lst:
        sum=a+fix_teen(b)+c
        if c in lst:
            sum=a+fix_teen(b)+fix_teen(c)
    elif c in lst:
        sum=a+b+fix_teen(c)
        if a in lst:
            sum=fix_teen(a)+b+fix_teen(c)
    else:
        sum=fix_teen(a)+fix_teen(b)+fix_teen(c)
    return sum
```

Output:

```
>>> no_teen_sum(14,1,13)
14                                                 #  the answer should be 1
>>> no_teen_sum(14,2,17)
19                                                 #  the answer should be 2
>>> no_teen_sum(16,17,18)
34                                                 # the answer should be 16

>>> no_teen_sum(17,18,19)
19                                                 # the answer should be 0
```

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Why did you write all that `lst` stuff when `fix_teen` was supposed to handle all of that?

Comment: Also, `fix_teen` was supposed to go outside `no_teen_sum`.

Comment: What happens when `a`is evaluated first, but `a`and `c`are "teens"? I think `if a in lst:
            sum=fix_teen(a)+b+fix_teen(c)` will never be executed.

Comment: @user2357112 Having `fix_teen` declared as an inner function within `no_teen_sum` makes sense from an encapsulation standpoint if nothing else in the code uses it.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton: Eh, it's as encapsulated as is useful at module level, and putting it at module level makes it much more testable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is how you wrote fix teen. You should simply send the number to fix teen and have it written like this:

```
def fix_teen(n):
    if (n >= 13 and n <=19):
        if (n!= 15 and n != 16):
            n = 0
    return n
```

Then your regular method could simply be:

```
def no_teen_sum(a,b,c):
    return fix_teen(a) + fix_teen(b) + fix_teen(c)
```

This will shorten your code and fix your mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You make things **supercomplicated**: you should **not write all those `if` statements**, simply generalizing the `fix_teen(n)` rule a bit is enough.

A number counts as *teen* given it is between 13 and 19, but not 15 or 16. So we can write:

```
def fix_teen(n):
    if n >= 13 and n <= 19 and (n < 15 or n > 16):
        return 0
    return n
```

Or more elegantly:

```
def fix_teen(n):
    if  13 <= n <= 19 and not (15 <= n <= 16):
        return 0
    return n
```

Next we can simply write:

```
def no_teen_sum(a,b,c):
    return sum(fix_teen(n) for n in (a,b,c))
```

We can easily generalize this using `*args` as well:

```
def no_teen_sum(*args):
    return sum(fix_teen(n) for n in args)
```

Now we can call it with an *arbitrary* number of values. This results in:

```
>>> no_teen_sum(14,1,13)
1
>>> no_teen_sum(14,2,17)
2
>>> no_teen_sum(16,17,18)
16
>>> no_teen_sum(17,18,19)
0
```

Comment: `in range(a, b)` is a bad way to do range tests, because it degrades to `O(b-a)` performance on Python 2 or for non-int input, and it silently returns `False` in many cases where you'd either want `True` or an exception.

Comment: @user2357112: no, in Python-3, it is done in *O(1)*. Take for instance `100 in range(1000,1000000000)`. This is handled in nanoseconds.

Comment: I did say "on Python 2 or for non-int input". With Python 3 and ints, it's O(1), but if you try it on Python 2, or if you inadvertently try it with `3.0` or `"3"`, it takes time proportional to the length of the range.

Comment: @user2357112: yeah I agree with that since it constructs a list of course. anyway, I showed a way to do it with comparsions.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler method with list comprehension:

```
def no_teen_sum(*args):  # *args means that it can take any number of arguments and pass it as a tuple to the function
    no_teens = [n for n in args if any([n in (15, 16), n not in range(13, 20)])]  # List comprehension that will iterate the passed arguments and omit anything between 13-19 except 15 & 16
    return sum(no_teens)  # return the sum
```

Edit: After reading your question again I noticed that you need a `teen_fix` method, I assume is a requirement for the assignment, in that case use the following solution, although the above one is perfectly valid.

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    no_teens = [teen_fix(n) for n in [a, b, c]]
    return sum(no_teens)

def teen_fix(n):
    return n if any([n in (15, 16), n not in range(13, 20)]) else 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `all(..)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: no, because if `n = 15` then `n in (15, 16)` evaluates to `True` and `n not in range(13, 20)` evaluates to `False`, in this case `all()` will evaluate to `False`.

Comment: Euh, yeah. I did not noticed you used negative logic.